# (x <= 100) тоже самое что и !(x > 100)?

Tags: javascript

На learnjs в тестах был такой вопросик:

[image: введите сюда описание изображния]
Я посчитал обе проверки полностью взаимозаменяемыми, но ответ, увы, другой. Какое должно быть значение дабы проверки давали разный результат?

```js
let numbers = [99,100,101];
numbers.forEach(number => {
  if (number <= 100) console.log('it\'s correct for '+number);
  else console.log('incorrect for '+number);
  if (!(number > 100)) console.log('it\'s correct for '+number);
  else console.log('incorrect for '+number);
})
```

Comment: Практически через минуту после создания вопроса осознал что значения - то могут быть не лишь числового типа, и если передать условный true, то проверки сработают по разному.

Comment: Какой-нибудь NaN надо проверить

Comment: ```undefined```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let number = NaN;
console.log(number <= 100);
console.log(!(number > 100));
```

Comment: Фактически ваш ответ верный, но кто в здравом уме будет такие проверки производить? По-моему сам факт наличия такой проверки уже говорит об ошибке в коде и её результат не имеет значения. Разве нет?

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf: ну так то ведь вопрос из теста, а там всегда творится "чушь, муть и компот"

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf, ну я один раз использовал NaN в качестве несуществующего id. И проверка `!(id > 0)` там тоже была. Ну и `undefined` при приведении к числу даёт `NaN`. Так что встретив такой кусок кода лучше не бросаться его рефакторить, а подумать, нафига оно так написано.

Comment: @Beast, какие? `number <= 100`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Любые. Проверка на больше или меньше подразумевает сравнение чисел. Если в такой проверке участвуют не числа, то это уже ошибка, даже если с точки зрения JS всё корректно.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf, ну по идее `typeof(NaN)` также `"number"`